# back4app parse, how to apply user object Id into another class pointer

Tags: function, pointers, objectid, back4app

so here is my code

```
void SignBusiness() async {
ParseUser currentUser = await ParseUser.currentUser() as ParseUser;
var nr = await currentUser.get('objectId');
ParseObject Data = await ParseObject('Business')
  ..set('NamaBisnis', _nama)
  ..set('AlamatBisnis', _alamat)
  ..set('KiloSampah', _kilo)
  ..set('Pemilik',nr);
await Data.save();
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/home', (route) => false);
```

}

this code works well and here is the result from run

```
I/flutter (14263): ╭-- Parse Request
```

`I/flutter (14263): curl -X POST -H 'content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' -H 'user-agent: Flutter Parse SDK 3.0.0' -H 'X-Parse-Application-Id: nQ1FGO9uklC7f9eMKYDuA16pvAjamCYnbI6xD2Zy' -H 'X-Parse-Session-Token: r:329114ed8d08441517f8a765ea22c902' -H 'X-Parse-Client-Key:` `gRsL6bmbByAL3p5CSvjF6nEL1VtHLsqHIVXzm0Or' -d '{"NamaBisnis":"faf","AlamatBisnis":"sss","KiloSampah":12,"Pemilik":"MOpxjAJCl2"}' https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/Business`

```
I/flutter (14263): 

I/flutter (14263):  https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/Business

I/flutter (14263): ╰--

I/flutter (14263): ╭-- Parse Response

I/flutter (14263): Class: Business

I/flutter (14263): Function: ParseApiRQ.create

I/flutter (14263): Status Code: 111

I/flutter (14263): Type: IncorrectType

I/flutter (14263): Error: schema mismatch for Business.Pemilik; expected Pointer<_User> but got String

I/flutter (14263): ╰--
```

it turn out the POINTER COLUMN cannot be filled with USER OBJECT ID.. even though they are the RIGHT CODE to fill in. so anyone can help on this one? please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the object (not only the id). It should be something like this:

```dart
void SignBusiness() async {
ParseUser currentUser = await ParseUser.currentUser() as ParseUser;
ParseObject Data = await ParseObject('Business')
  ..set('NamaBisnis', _nama)
  ..set('AlamatBisnis', _alamat)
  ..set('KiloSampah', _kilo)
  ..set('Pemilik', currentUser);
await Data.save();
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/home', (route) => false);
```